# ListTile not distinguish each item

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working with BlockBuilder and it include a ListTile. But I click on one item, other items event click too. When I push it to new screen, it is one item, but I don't know why it isn't distinguished each other.

This is my code in Android Studio:

```
      Widget _buildListTile(ProductItemModel item) {
    final bool alreadySaved = _saved.contains(item);
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        item.name,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      subtitle: Text("Price: " + item.price),
      leading: Container(
        width: 69,
        height: 40,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54)),
        child: Image.network(item.icon),
      ),
      trailing: new Icon(
        alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
      ),
      // event ontap to catch like/ don't like
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (alreadySaved) {
            _saved.remove(item);
            print("move"+item.name);
          } else {
            _saved.add(item);
            print("add"+item.name);
          }
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

This data from model, but I can't understand them....

```
This is my api, i get data from this...    


class ProductApiProvider {
      Future<ProductModel> getListProduct() async {
        //await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
        return ProductModel.fromJson([
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "RTX 2070s",
            "price" : "1.190 USD",
            "icon" : "https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/518866-nvidia-geforce-rtx-2080-founders-edition-7.jpg?width=810&height=456",
            "isLove" : false

          },
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "RTX 2080",
            "price" : "1.999 USD",
            "icon" : "https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/518013-yeah-it-s-a-beast.jpg?width=810&height=456",
            "isLove" : false
          },

          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Mainboard Z390",
            "price" : "499 USD",
            "icon" : "https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/610433-meet-the-asrock-z390-taichi.jpg?thumb=y&width=980&height=456",
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Main Z370",
            "price" : "349 USD",
            "icon" : "https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/498346-image-aorus-jpg.jpg?width=810&height=456",
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "I3 8100",
            "price" : "199 USD",
            "icon" : "https://assets.pcmag.com/media/images/465550-cpu-showdown-intel-core-i3-vs-i5.jpg?thumb=y&width=810&height=456"
          },
        ]);
      }
    }
```

and this is my model

```
This is my model

class ProductItemModel extends Equatable
    {
      final int id;
      final String name;
      final String price;
      final String icon;
      final bool isLove;

      ProductItemModel({this.id, this.name, this.price, this.icon, this.isLove});

      factory ProductItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> item)
      {
        return ProductItemModel(
          id: item["id"],
          name: item["name"],
          price: item["price"],
          icon: item["icon"],
          isLove: item["isLove"]
        );
      }
    }

    class ProductModel
    {
      List<ProductItemModel> listProduct;

      ProductModel(this.listProduct);

      factory ProductModel.fromJson(List<dynamic> json)
      {
        List<ProductItemModel> mapProduct = List<ProductItemModel>.from(json.map((item){
          return ProductItemModel.fromJson(item);
        }));

        return ProductModel(mapProduct);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you define the `==` operator for your `ProductItemModel` class? The `.contains()` method compares the elements against one another using this operator.

Comment: Can you tell me how to define my ProductItemModel, i'm just beginner flutter for a month.

Comment: Can you share your `ProductItemModel` class code?

Comment: i just update my model below